# Allow the user to turn on or off (basically hide) any number of database fields?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, datastore, nosql

I've got an interesting high level programming question: I have a data entry Rails app with a MySQL database. I've got the schema programmed out for someone who would use all of the database fields in the app.

However, there are going to be users who may want to only use say, half, of those fields. They have a smaller operation going on and don't track as much data. They should be able to turn on or off any of those fields so that they don't see them when inputting or viewing their data.

Now, I could create a table with a foreign key to the user (or account in my case), with boolean values for every single field in my app - but there over a hundred, and then every time I modified the schema of the app, I would have to modify this table as well. Then I would use the table to conditionally hide or show these fields.

I can't think of any other way than that, which is really less than ideal.

Are there any other databases that would fit this type of situation better, like a NoSQL or document store, or PostgreSQL? Or can anyone come up with a better game plan on a high level for a problem like this?

Comment: Views my dear sir, Views.

Comment: I'd leave the tables unchanged, and treat this as a user configuration property that's handled purely at the presentation layer in the UI.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm definitely going to have to have it interact with the presentation/view/UI. "if the user has this field enabled, show it". I just need a good way - or, the best way - to store this data.

Comment: Ah, right. I'd store it as a set of (userid, fieldname) tuples, where the presence of a tuple means the field is to be hidden. If you wanted to reduce the number of such entries, at the cost of flexibility, you could define sets or categories of fields in the app, and just store those.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm going with for now is to stick with MySQL and just use rails to serialize an array of database fields to be hidden. This will probably be the approach that I use unless anyone else offers some better insight.

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem I think `MongoDB` is perfect because of it's schemaless nature.

MongoDB is a JSON-style data store.  The documents stored in the database can have varying sets of fields, with different types for each field.  One could have the following objects in a single collection:

```
{ a : “Joe”, b : 3.3, c : [1,2,3] }

{ a : “Kate”, x : “abc” }

{ q : 456 }
```

Of course, when using the database for real problems, the data does have a fairly consistent structure.  Something like the following would be more common:

```
{ name : “Deepak”, age : 30, interests : ‘cricket’ }

{ name : “Greg”, age : 25 }
```

So in your case you can store whatever field is required for each user and show only those which are really exist.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can grant permissions not only on tables, but also on columns.

Your application can use has_column_privilege() to figure out, if a specific user can read from that column - and then show the column, or not.